# Http Post request in Microsoft Bot Composer

Tags: botframework

I have tried below but http request got fails is there I missing something can anyone guide me please. In postman by using qnaId in the body I am getting the correspond queastion and answer in json response. The same I have tried in composer with Http request but it fails.
{
"qnaId" : "1164"
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTbxa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNKDR.png)

The same I tried in Postman and successfully got the response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm0N1.png)

Thanks....

Comment: You`ll need to provide some runtime context. Add the http request & response details with status and any error details along with a description of the investigation you have made. did you compare the postman request & response to the bot composer request & response to see how they differ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `$Qna` is not a valid memory variable. Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-memory), you need to set this in either conversation, dialog, turn or user scopes. I had missed the section in the post [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/6670) where the response was being set to `$Qna`. That's not valid. So, it needs something like `turn.Qna` or `dialog.Qna`.

Additionally, the use of `$` should be used only for string interpolation, not in setting the variable name. `turn.Qna` would set it and you would utilize it in a string as: `"You said: ${turn.Qna}"`

Comment: Tried above solution but same problem request failed.

Comment: working fine now I tried this and worked.{
  "qnaId": "${dialog.qnaId}"
}